# How to check json key and value is available inside json file

Tags: python, json

I want to check is `"Code":"A"` avaiable in json file. I already searching on internet and read many QA in stackoverflow but it does not help me. Could anyone show me how to do it?

```
with open(dummyJson_url):
    dataList = json.load(open(dummyJson_url))

test = json.loads("""{"Code":"A"}""")

racksLocation = dataList["Test"]

for i in range(len(racksLocation)):

    newLoc = dataList["Test"][i]

    if sorted(test.items()) in sorted(newLoc.items()):
        print("Yes")
        break

    else:
        print("No")
```

and here is my json:

```
{
    "Test": [
        {
            "Code":"A",
            "Buyer": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"B",
            "New": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"C",
            "Racks": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"D",
            "Baru": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple problem:

```
>>> print(sorted(test.items()))
[('Code', 'A')] #a list with 1 item(tuple) in it

>>> print(sorted(newLoc.items()))
[('Buyer', []), ('Code', 'A')] #a list with 2 tuples
```

So when you are trying this:

```
if sorted(test.items()) in sorted(newLoc.items()):
   ...
```

the condition fails because `[('Code', 'A')]` is NOT in `[('Buyer', []), ('Code', 'A')]` but `('Code', 'A')` is! (notice the lack of list brackets here)

All you need to do is access the first(and only) element in `[('Code', 'A')]` (which is `sorted(test.items())[0]`)

This is all you need to do using just your approach if you prefer to stick with it(which could improve but I wont get into it):

```
with open(dummyJson_url):
    dataList = json.load(open(dummyJson_url))

test = json.loads("""{"Code":"A"}""")

racksLocation = dataList["Test"]

for i in range(len(racksLocation)):

    newLoc = dataList["Test"][i]

    if sorted(test.items())[0] in sorted(newLoc.items()): #you are now checking the first element inside the list
        print("Yes")
        break

    else:
        print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified your code:

```
with open(dummyJson_url):
    dataList = json.load(open(dummyJson_url))

for item in datalist['Test']:
    if 'Code' in item and item['Code'] == "A":
        print 'yes'
        break
    else:
        print 'no'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `json.loads(json_string)` it gives you dictionary if you get for example `json_data={"a":1}` if you do `json_data.get("a")` it will give you value 1 if present or `None` so simply you can check you can make a resulable function for this

```
 def check_in_json(jsondata,key,value):
       for data in jsondata:
           if data.get(key) == value:
              return True
       return False
```

And call it like

```
json_data={
    "Test": [
        {
            "Code":"A",
            "Buyer": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"B",
            "New": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"C",
            "Racks": []
        },
        {
            "Code":"D",
            "Baru": []
        }
    ]
}

check_in_json(json_data["Test"],"Code","A") #you will get True if found else false
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with your approach, Try below code:

```
with open(dummyJson_url):
    dataList = json.load(open(dummyJson_url))

test = {"Code":"A"}

for data in dataList["Test"]:
    if test.items() <= data.items():   # In dict, .items() would give you the set type which can be compared.
        print("Yes")
        break
    else:
        print("No")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject class has a method named "has":

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)